# Feed list of variables into table R

Tags: r, vector, contingency

Here is my example:

```
set.seed(1)
col_1 <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE)
col_2 <- sample(LETTERS[5:8],1000, replace = TRUE)
col_3 <- sample(LETTERS[9:12],1000, replace = TRUE)
sample_df <- data.frame(col_1,col_2,col_3)
```

I can get contingency table with the following line:

```
with(df,table(col_1, col_2))
```

Now in case I have many variables, I would like use vector inside table, something like this:

```
my_var <- c('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3)
with(sample_df, table(my_var))
```

but it does not work. Any workaround?

Comment: @joel.wilson Thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as simple as it could be !

```
table(sample_df[my_var])
```